# Scipy interp2d for large data file

Tags: python, scipy, large-data, linear-interpolation

Edit from the beginning:

I want to interpolate txt data file (has three columns x, y and z this time) using interp2d. The shape of the file is (1756612, 3) and the data is like, x,y,z=

```
[[  0.1569    0.1161   -0.0432 ]
[ -0.1063    0.2548    0.1365 ]
[  0.3046    0.07185   0.2372 ]
..., 
[ 12.03      0.279     2.227  ]
[  7.851     0.6597   -0.5134 ]
[ 22.68      0.1968    3.752  ]]
```

My goal is to interpolate onto a 2D grid where the axes are 1st column,i.e. x, and 2nd and 3rd columns together, y and z. The last two columns are linked via equation f= sqrt(y^2+z^2) and I then want to plot this as a pcolor type of plot.

However, I’ve got the following error,

```
f = interp2d(x, y, Z, kind='linear')
File "/Users/Reem/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 218, in __init__
"Invalid length for input z for non rectangular grid")
ValueError: Invalid length for input z for non rectangular grid
```

How do I fix this error message? and how do I involve x column on this correctly? I have not been able to figure it out. I will gladly provide more information if required.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Get the data from the file
data = np.genfromtxt('data_pxpypz.txt')
#print(data.shape) 
#print(data)

xdata = data[:,0]  # 1st col data
ydata = data[:,1]  # 2nd col data 
zdata = data[:,2]  # 3rd col data


# # set the grid using minimum and maximum values of ydata and zdata
x = np.arange(-50, 36, 1) 
y = np.arange(-50, 36, 1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# calculate the function from ydata and zdata
Z = np.sqrt(ydata**2+zdata**2)

# set the new grid as well as the interplating results
x2 = np.arange(-50, 36, 0.1)
y2 = np.arange(-50, 36, 0.1)
f = interp2d(x, y, Z, kind='linear')
Z2 = f(x2, y2)
# #
# # 

# plot the results

plt.pcolor(X, Y, Z)
X2, Y2 = np.meshgrid(x2, y2)
plt.pcolor(X2, Y2, Z2)

plt.show()
```

Comment: 2d-Interpolation is needed for data, which is a function of two independent variables, so _if_ the two columns _would_ be yor two axes - where is your dependent data variable? tbh: I don't think that you want to use interp2d here. Are you really sure? What brought you to the idea to 2d-interpolate this data? And why interpolating, don't you just want to plot in a first step to see if Interpolation is needed? May I ask what the source of the data is?

Comment: @SpghttCd: I plotted those data and they're scattered data. To get meaning of them, I found they need to be interpolated. I did 1D interpolation but I what to do it as pcolor type of plot.

Comment: @SpghttCd: Those data represent particles momentums generated from my simulation. I'm thinking of taking those 2D array and interpolating the particles additively onto the grid.  This will then give a 2D surface that I can visualize much more easily.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand how this data could be visualized in 2d. Is one column dependent of the other? If you said you made a scatter plot, it seems so; at least you're interested in the relation of those two with each other.

Comment: Does this data mean that at `x,y` = `[  0.1569    0.12388]` there is a point (with `z` value of 1)?  And a total of 1756612 points in x,y space?

Comment: @SpghttCd and @hpaulj; Apologies. It seems I didn't set my question properly. I will edit it and back one more step in this processes. It might this would be useful.

Comment: hope it is clear this time. Thanks for help

Comment: Hi all. I think I found that answer. I have to write the function as Z = np.sqrt(X**2+Y**2). Many thanks for all great questions and discussions.